# Filtering a column per a maximum value to show on histogram

Tags: qliksense

I want to show on the histogram only the values from the 2nd major week.

Example: I have this table with "Week" and "feature_value". And week "6" is the 2nd major week.

Week    feature_value
3   10,1
4   10,5
5   10,7
5   10,3
6   11,1
6   10,7
7   10,3

Basically What I want is this:

Week    feature_value
6   11,1
6   10,7

I succeed doing it in qliksense table with this formula:

`=Num(Aggr(distinct IF(max(Week,2),feature_value),feature_value))`

But, when I use it on the histogram it appears "The chart is not displayed because it contains only undefined values."

See below the error:

[image: wcamargo_0-1676226636459.png]

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you are using an `Aggr()`. This is because under the hood, Qlik is taking whatever dimension you provide it and is formatting it into this expression: `Class(aggr({{Dim[0]}},{{Dim[0]}}){{BinSize}}{{Label}}{{Offset}})`. You can't use an `Aggr()` inside of another `Aggr()`, at least not in this case.

What you need to do is use a field-on-the-fly like this: `If([Week] = $(=Max(all [Week], 2)), [feature_value])`. This is similar to what you had tried but doesn't use the `Aggr()` and makes sure to put the needed `Max()` aggregation inside of a `$()` expression, such that it evaluates over `all` values regardless of what's been selected.